# New dual processor server does not boot

Tags: hardware, boot

I'm building a machine and having a nightmare getting it to boot. It turns on, but does not display anything on the screen and the 7 Segment LED on the motherboard shows QCode 61, which according to the manual is nvram initialization.

The components are:

MotherBoard
https://www.asus.com/nl/Commercial_Servers_Workstations/Z10PED8_WS/

Processor
2 x 10 core Xenon

Ram:
8 x G.SKILL F4-2133C15Q-16GRB

I've tried putting different ram in different slots and using less Ram but with no luck.

Does anyone know what this issue is likely to be and any steps to resolve it.

I have followed the locations on the motherboard manual that the ram should be placed.

Comment: And that is why the professional approach is to buy a complete system, complete with warranty, instead of wasting time to fix this yourself.

Comment: Is this for a server or a workstation?  This question might be off topic for serverfault.  But it's likely either RAM comparability or the BIOS needs updating to the support the particular CPU you're using. Which you haven't specified.

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard you are using calls for RDIMM (Registered RAM).  You are using UDIMM (Unbuffered RAM).  ECC Registered RAM is standard for most Xeons except for the E3 models.